# Exchange 2010 and 2003 Co-Existence - Mail flow and Public folder issues

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, exchange-migration

Hopefully someone out there can help me out.

As the subject says i have exchange 2010 and 2003 in a co-existence mode. I have configured public folder replications and plan to use the powershell script to do the final MOVE of the public folders: `.\MoveAllReplicas.ps1 -Server “Exchange2003″ -NewServer “Exchange2010″`

I got this information from the following source: http://careexchange.in/moving-public-folders-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010/

I was about to use the `MoveAllReplicas.ps1` powershell script when I had the idea to first test the replicas by dismounting the legacy (2003) public folder mail store, this was to ensure the folders were still available via the primary server (2010). I noticed once all dismounted the public folder store (so all stores are not dismounted on the legacy server) some emails began to queue within 'Messages awaiting directory lookup' on the legacy server.

Since all mail stores were dismounted, as a test I mounted a mail store at random (non public folder), did a force connection and refresh. All the emails disappeared from this list.

When all mail stores are dismounted on the legacy server some of the outbound emails sent by users who reside on the primary server (2010) are being routed via the legacy server. I can then see these emails queued and they will not be sent until a remount at least one mail store.

E.g. All mailbox stores are dismounted on the legacy exchange, John Smith's account is located on primary exchange (2010). John sends an email and I see it stuck in the queue on the legacy server 'Messages awaiting directory lookup'.

NOTE: This does not happen for all users, It seems to happen at Random.

I attempted to fix the issue by creating a new 'Send Connector' with a lower cost and defining the 'Source server as the primary server (2010). Unfortunately some emails are still sending via the legacy server.

With regards to the public folders, I used the following to add the replicas between the legacy and primary exchange:

`.\AddReplicaToPFRecursive.ps1 -TopPublicFolder “\” -ServerToAdd “Exchange2010″`
When i dismount the public folders all the public folders are accessible via the 2010 server so it seems the replications have worked.

So my questions are:

1. Why are some outbound emails being sent out via the legacy server even though these users mailboxes reside on the primary exchange  (2010)?
2. Why would the legacy exchange require a mailstore to be mounted for mail flow to work coming from the 2010 server?
3. Would the AddReplicaToPFRecursive.ps1 command not have added the replicas to all the public folders including the system public folders? E.g SCHEDULE+FREE BUSY, OFFLINE ADDRESS LIST, EFORMS REGISTRY etc

Thanks in advance.